# How can I add padding to StackPane using hbox

Tags: java, javafx

I'm still learning how to mess around with panels and hbox,vbox etc..
I want to be able to set paddings around the center of StackPane.

```
@Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.setTitle("GUIGUI");
       
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10); // number sets spacing between things
        
        Button roll1 = new Button("Roll");
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40,40,40,40));
        hbox.getChildren().add(roll1);  
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.setAlignment(hbox, Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().add(hbox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();  
        
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
         
    }
...
```

I've tried using hbox to set padding around roll(which is a button) so that it will have padding of 40,40,40,40 when it's called(?) in StackPane.

My code sets padding around the button, but it is not positioned in center even though I've done

```
root.setAlignment(hbox, Pos.CENTER);
```

Comment: [mcve] please..

Answer (score 1):

You might want something like this. This adds padding to your StackPane and centers your button.
Make sure you have only javafx imports and not awt imports.

```
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        stage.setTitle("GUIGUI");
       
        HBox hbox = new HBox(10); // number sets spacing between things
        
        Button roll1 = new Button("Roll");
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40,40,40,40));
        hbox.getChildren().add(roll1);
        hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color:TAN");
        
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(hbox);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(40,40,40,40));
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color:BLUE");
        

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();  
        
    }
```

Comment: i cant see hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40,40,40,40));, padding but its there correct?

Comment: Yes. To see this padding's effects, remove the line hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); and remove the HBox's padding. Run the Application. roll1 should end up on the top left of the HBox. Now add the HBox's padding back (but do not put the alignment line back), and run the Application. You should now see that roll1 is a different position (but still on the top left).

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure about what you are trying to do, but I think you should give the `HBox` a preferred size. Then you should set the `HBox` max size to `USE_PREF_SIZE`.

**I updated the answer using @Kleopatra's advice.**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Control;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setTitle("GUIGUI");

        HBox hbox = new HBox(10); // number sets spacing between things
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
        Button roll1 = new Button("Roll");
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(40, 40, 40, 40));
        hbox.getChildren().add(roll1);
        hbox.setMaxSize(Control.USE_PREF_SIZE, Control.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(hbox);
        root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: green");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: ehh .. no - hard-coding sizes is wrong _always_ ;) And you don't need it: for a Stackpane, it's enough to limit the max of the hbox (as you correctly do via use_pref) plus adding a padding (as in the question) - and center align is default :) Just in a nit-picking mood, on a grey Sunday in November ..

Comment: @kleopatra, Thanks! With your advice, I will eventually become a master of `JavaFX`.